# How to know which table in flow documents that want to be edit?

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, flowdocument

I am new in richtext box and flow documents,
I am trying to make program similar to word (user can write and add multiple table)

Here is my xaml code

```
                           <DockPanel Grid.Column="1">
                                <ToolBar x:Name="ToolBarUntenRight" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                                    <ToggleButton x:Name="ToolStripButtonBold" Command="EditingCommands.ToggleBold" ToolTip="Bold">
                                        <Image Source="Images/Bold.png" Stretch="None"/>
                                    </ToggleButton>
                                    <ToggleButton x:Name="ToolStripButtonItalic" Command="EditingCommands.ToggleItalic" ToolTip="Italic">
                                        <Image Source="Images/Italic.png" Stretch="None"/>
                                    </ToggleButton>
                                    <ToggleButton x:Name="ToolStripButtonUnderline" Command="EditingCommands.ToggleUnderline" ToolTip="Underline">
                                        <Image Source="Images/Underline.png" Stretch="None"/>
                                    </ToggleButton>
                                    <Separator/>
                                    <Button Content="Table" Click="addTable_Click"></Button>
                                    <Button Content="Row +" Click="addrow_Click"></Button>
                                    <Button Content="Row -" Click="removerow_Click"></Button>
                                    <Button Content="Col +" Click="addcolumn_Click"></Button>
                                    <Button Content="Col -" Click="removecolumn_Click"></Button>
                                </ToolBar>
                                <RichTextBox x:Name="RichTextControlRight" SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" AcceptsReturn="True" AcceptsTab="True" SelectionChanged="RichTextControl_SelectionChanged" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
                            </DockPanel>
```

And my code behind

```
private void addTable_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Add blank line
        flowDoc.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run(" ")));

        Table table1 = new Table();

        table1.CellSpacing = 0;
        table1.Background = Brushes.White;

        int numberOfColumns = 3;
        int numberOfRows = 3;

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfColumns; i++)
        {
            table1.Columns.Add(new TableColumn());
        }

        table1.RowGroups.Add(new TableRowGroup());

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfColumns; i++)
        {
            table1.RowGroups[0].Rows.Add(new TableRow());

            for (int j = 0; j < numberOfRows; j++)
            {
                table1.RowGroups[0].Rows[i].Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(i + " " + j))));
            }
        }

        foreach (var item in table1.RowGroups[0].Rows)
        {
            foreach (var item2 in item.Cells)
            {
                item2.BorderBrush = Brushes.Black;
                item2.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1, 1, 1, 1);
            }
        }

        flowDoc.Blocks.Add(table1);

        //Add blank line
        flowDoc.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run(" ")));
    }
```

Currently I am struggling on make add row, remove row, add column, and remove column feature

I want the user able to select which table that he/she want to edit, then click the add row button

[image]

but I dont know how to detect that

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I tried using  
table1.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(doSomething);
It kinda work, if the mouse didnt pass other table

Comment: is there a select or hightlight table event? try mouseup event, doesnt firing